# ios app is not launching after installing via link

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipa

I want to share my app with a link. So I uploaded .ipa file to  [web server](https://i.diawi.com/X6MpiL)
But after installing app is not launching and has gray icon for some reasons.

[image: gray]

Comment: How did you sign the app?  Is it an ad-hoc build?  If so, does it include the UUID of your device in the provisioning profile?

Comment: as I understood so far I didn't include an ID in the provisioning profile. Is there a way to share my app (w.o appstore) not including every device ID in provisioning profile?
I'm trying to share my app with word(w.o appstore)

Comment: No, that is one of the main features of the Apple App Store system; Apps that are generally available need to be reviewed by Apple and published through the App Store. You can use ad-hoc distribution for testing if you have a few known UUIDs and there are some other methods for enterprise in-house apps.  You can also use TestFlight in App Store Connect to allow people to test your app.